# Typical random keyboard input, in various cultures

Tags: data-request

Wikipedia receives a huge number of text additions per day, each falling in one of these categories:

1. Good-faith addition: `in 1789`
2. Subtle misinformation: `in 1790`
3. Spam: `in any CostMart store`
4. Immature vandalism: `in YOUR MOM lol`
5. Random keyboard input vandalism: `wqefeqesfdqwedqw`

This question is about **case 5** only.
A detection algorithm considers:

- The behavior of human fingers
- The keyboard layout depending on the device (desktop/mobile/etc) and the culture (QWERTY/AZERTY/ЙЦУКЕН/InScript/Arabic/etc)

To train/test the algorithm, I need large quantities of random keyboard input.

- At least 5000 strings
- Bonus if for each string the device and culture is known, but it is not strictly required

Example:

```
kdakllkdkldslkdskds, QWERTY
あけさにめはよたかひや, FSKARENテンキー
```

Comment: Can you use the random char string generator?

Comment: @Y.N: I need the data to train/test an algorithm. Generated data would not work for this, real-world data is needed.

Comment: Could you train it on WP data? eg/ look at reverted edits and pull out the ones where the diff is, say, more than 10 characters and does not contain any dictionary words? This would predominantly be case 5 examples.

Comment: @Andrew: Yeah that would be a great source of data! But it is not trivial to extract, so if someone has done the work I would gladly re-use their data :-) Case 5 is actually a rather rare occurrence, so I guess 95% of the words found by the technique you described would be 1) Words that are not in the dictionary, because any Wikipedia article has 5%-10% of words that are not in my dictionary, like proper nouns, jargon, abbreviations 2) Technical wikicode such as `refimprove` or `pp-move-indef`. Cheers!

Comment: Not free, but you can ask Amazon MTurk's workers.